# Selecting specific length of characters in a dataset

Tags: r

I have a proteomics dataset with a list of peptides. e.g.

```
x = c("DFGVEVDNNSYK","EFHIR","VGQEYQPR","AYQVEGDWSGAAFMLVAGAIAGSIEVENLNTR","SHQADR","AILDALK","LR").
```

I want to extract a list peptides where the peptide length is between 4-10. How can I do this with

```
nchar?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `nchar()` function:

```
x <- c("DFGVEVDNNSYK", "EFHIR", "VGQEYQPR", "AYQVEGDWSGAAFMLVAGAIAGSIEVENLNTR", "SHQADR", "AILDALK", "LR")
output <- x[nchar(x) >= 4 & nchar(x) <= 10]
output

[1] "EFHIR"    "VGQEYQPR" "SHQADR"   "AILDALK"
```